# How do I remove a stuck valve cover?

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, valve-cover, katana

On my 1994 Suzuki Katana 600, it is way overdue for valve adjustment.  Unfortunately I'm unable to get the valve cover off.  I have what appear to be all the bolts removed (there's 14 of them across 3 different types, plus 4 more for the oil cooler lines).  I suspect it's just stuck in place from old age.  I've been tapping around the edges with a rubber mallet, but no luck.  I'm afraid I'm going to need a more aggressive method...

Comment: If all else fails, get a bigger hammer. If something breaks, it needed replaced anyway ... ;-) J/K

Comment: Try lightly tapping a plastic or wood wedge into the crack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parts diagram shows 14 fasteners.  Qty. 8, 2, and 4 of #5, #6, and #8 respsectively.

After that you should be able to separate the cover from the cylinder head.  If it won't come off with gentle tapping, try prying with a paint scraper or similar thin bladed tool.  You'll want to be careful not to scratch the surface of the cylinder head.  If you have a plastic scraper, that would be better to start with since the plastic will not scratch the Aluminum of the head and cover.

[image: Katana 600 Valve Cover]